# cant start mongodb strange behavior permission denied as root

Tags: unix, mongodb, solaris

Im running as `root` on a smartos64 machine.

- My database is at `/data/db`
- Mongod is at `/mongo/bin/mongod`

I get a 'permission denied' error with no further details when running either
 - `run ./mongo/bin/mongod` *or*
 - `sudo ./mongo/bin/mongod`

I tried changing permissions with chown on `/data/db`, but I still get this behaviour. How would I start mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What build of Mongo did you download? I believe SmartOS64 is a derivative of Solaris, so I would try a Solaris build from the Mongo download site. If that doesn't work, you may want to build it from source.

Comment: just gave that a shot with x86 and i86 (prebuilt binary) for solaris 64 and 32 but same thing

Comment: thanks I built from source and turned out im missing the mongo64-extra modules